# Compare items in a List to each other, by a seperate function

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have a function that checks whether a string represents a filesystemlocation beneath another string. My question however should be applicable to any function returning boolean.

Here is the function anyway...

```
private bool IsItemBelowPath(string item, string path)
{

    if (path == Path.GetPathRoot(path))
    {
        path = path.TrimEnd('\\');
    }

    if (item.Length < path.Length + 2)
        return false;

    return (string.Compare(item, 0, path, 0, path.Length, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0 &&
        item[path.Length] == Path.DirectorySeparatorChar);

}
```

I have a List that contains file and folder paths that I like to filter (with above function) so that no nesting occur.

**These paths**

- C:\Path
- C:\Path\SubPath
- C:\Path\File.txt
- D:\
- D:\Path
- D:\File.txt

**Should become**

- C:\Path
- D:\

I need to compare all paths with all other ones and return the correct ones.

I'm quite new to development but suspect that a LINQ statement, using the function above, could accomplish this, i've tried the following but it gives wrong result

```
var items = new List<string> { my paths.... } 

return (from i1 in items
        from i2 in items
        where !IsItemBelowPath(i1, i2)
        select i2).Distinct().ToList();
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative approach that is easier to read, has better performance, and gives the correct result is to iterate over the items and use `Any` to test if any of the other items are a sub-path of that item:

```
var query = items
    .Where(i1 => !items.Any(i2 => IsItemBelowPath(i1, i2)))
    .ToList();
```

Result:

```
C:\Path
D:\
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
return (from item in items
        where items.Any(parent => IsItemBelowPath(parent,item))
        select item);
```

In your code you're considering every pair, and there's bound to be at least one where one is not a sub-path of the other.

Comment: I like this as it's more readable than the one above but it misses items that doesn't have children. Add @"E:\Path" to my paths above to test.